# Timescaledb memory consumption remains very low even when there is a lot of data

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgresql-11, timescaledb

I have a timescaledb setup where I periodically dump data (every 10 mins or so). It is deployed using docker-compose.

The data consists of an entity_id and a measurement and a couple of other things like region etc.

A typical query is `get per day minimum for last 30 days for an entity_id`.

```sql
    SELECT
        time_bucket_gapfill('1 day', time, date_trunc('day', now() - interval '30 days'), date_trunc('day', now())) AS one_day,
        country,
        type_id,
        min(measurement)
    FROM hypertable
    WHERE
        entity_id='XYZ' AND
        country='US' AND
        time > time_bucket('1 day', now() - interval '30 days') AND 
        time < time_bucket('1 day', now())
    GROUP BY one_day, country, type_id
```

- The server has 8GB of RAM.
- Chunk interval is set to 1 day.
- Each chunk's size is about 4.5GB

  ```
                 chunk_table             | table_size | index_size | total_size
  ---------------------------------------|-------------------------|------------
  _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_1_chunk |   696 MB   |  1675 MB   |   2370 MB
  _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_2_chunk |  1318 MB   |  3223 MB   |   4540 MB
  _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_3_chunk |  1318 MB   |  3222 MB   |   4539 MB
  _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_4_chunk |  1318 MB   |  3223 MB   |   4540 MB
  ```

The db currently has about 24 chunks (24 days of data).

I have been doing some benchmarking and load testing using `wrk` and found that a significant number of queries take several seconds to complete.
The problem I am seeing is that the ram usage of timescaledb remains at about 50MB. And goes to about 100MB during the load test running the above query while the CPU usage and Disk IO shoot up significantly.

My expectation was that about one chunk (the recent one) worth of data will be in RAM.
Even if that assumption is wrong, the ram usage doesn't increase when the 30 day query is issued.

I want to understand whether this is an expected behaviour or there is some problem with the setup.

I tried setting memory reservation and memory limits to the docker container but it had no effect.

Comment: There is a [timescaledb slack channel](https://slack-login.timescale.com/) where you could probably ask the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory consumption of PostgreSQL is mostly related to:

[shared_buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY): Constant amount of memory for the whole PostgreSQL instance, shared between all sessions.
[work_mem](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) Amount of memory available for sort/hash operations in a session. This could be used multiple times per session.

If you have memory to spare on your DB Server, it would make sense to increase `shared_buffers`, so more data is kept in memory. Conventional wisdom says that 25% of available RAM is a good starting point. As you use docker-compose you probably share this server with other processes, so you may want to adjust this to take that into account.

You could/should also increase `work_mem` so that more hash/sort operations use memory instead of disk. `work_mem` is a variable that can be set in your session, so you try a few things, compare the following for example:

```
feike=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ON, BUFFERS ON) SELECT * FROM pg_class ORDER BY relfilenode;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=230.82..234.95 rows=1652 width=782) (actual time=3.149..3.477 rows=1680 loops=1)
   Sort Key: relfilenode
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1246kB
   Buffers: shared hit=126
   ->  Seq Scan on pg_class  (cost=0.00..142.52 rows=1652 width=782) (actual time=0.015..0.627 rows=1680 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=126
 Planning Time: 0.193 ms
 Execution Time: 3.908 ms
(8 rows)

feike=# set work_mem to '64kB';
SET
feike=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ON, BUFFERS ON) SELECT * FROM pg_class ORDER BY relfilenode;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=1371.82..1375.95 rows=1652 width=782) (actual time=6.675..8.102 rows=1680 loops=1)
   Sort Key: relfilenode
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 832kB
   Buffers: shared hit=126, temp read=239 written=268
   ->  Seq Scan on pg_class  (cost=0.00..142.52 rows=1652 width=782) (actual time=0.015..0.654 rows=1680 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=126
 Planning Time: 0.192 ms
 Execution Time: 8.993 ms
(8 rows)
```

The main difference in the plans being:

```
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 832kB
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1246kB
```

The best way for you to find out if `work_mem` would be useful is to do a:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ON, BUFFERS ON)
    SELECT
        time_bucket_gapfill('1 day', time, date_trunc('day', now() - interval '30 days'), date_trunc('day', now())) AS one_day,
        country,
        type_id,
        min(measurement)
    FROM hypertable
    WHERE
        entity_id='XYZ' AND
        country='US' AND
        time > time_bucket('1 day', now() - interval '30 days') AND 
        time < time_bucket('1 day', now())
    GROUP BY one_day, country, type_id
```

And look for any disk operations.

The line looking like this:

```
Buffers: shared hit=96 read=44152
```

Informs you about your `shared_buffers`, how many times did it find what it needed (`hit`) and how often did it have to fetch something from disk (`read`).

A bit too long of an answer, but the gist of it is that you need to size your PostgreSQL instance to your workload; the defaults for PostgreSQL are (very) conservative which allows it to run pretty much anywhere. You however seem to want to use the database in earnest, so some tuning is required.

Some tools out there to help you do this:

- https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-tune
- https://github.com/iterativo-git/pgtune

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Feike. I was able to tweak the parameters to suite my server. For tuning, there is also https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua